# Opinion on Li Quingzhao poem calligraphy effort

Tags: calligraphy, poetry, transliteration, reading

I tried to write two lines of Li Quingzhao's poem in semi-cursive, I searched for the hanzis in other calligraphies and that's the first result.

[image]

Is it readable? Do the hanzis make sense or I used too different calligraphies?

Elsewhere, do you know where I can find an example of this very same poem in cursive / semi-cursive?

Thank you so much in advantage.

Comment: Her name is 'Li Qingzhao' rather than 'Li Quingzhao'

Answer (score 1):

[生當作人傑，死亦為鬼雄](https://www.epochtimes.com/b5/7/8/2/n1790585.htm)

> 「**生當作人傑，死亦為鬼雄**。至今思[項羽](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%B9%E7%BE%BD)，不肯過江東。」

> *出自[李清照](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%8E%E6%B8%85%E7%85%A7)的〈夏日絕句〉*

> "**One should be an elite in life and a hero in death**. To this day, I still think of Xiang Yu who refused to retreat to Gong Dung."

> *From "Summer Quatrains" by Li Qingzhao*

> Is it readable?

I can read it

> do you know where I can find an example of this very same poem in cursive / semi-cursive?

Check [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=5821ba678cbe793b&sxsrf=ACQVn08zP280w3htcHK0bLq2qScE3FfQjg:1710113462723&q=%E7%94%9F%E7%95%B6%E5%81%9A%E4%BA%BA%E5%82%91%20%E6%AD%BB%E4%BA%A6%E7%82%BA%E9%AC%BC%E9%9B%84&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjh-KL7eqEAxXGFFkFHUKGAGsQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1574&bih=735&dpr=2.4)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, would you consider this good calligraphy or bad calligraphy? Is it easy to read or did I write some hanzi in a weird way? I searched them from different places, does the choice of the different styles make sense?

Comment: There really is no good or bad when it comes to calligraphy as it really is an art. Your stylization of 鬼雄 is definitely written less conventionally. Personally, I really like the way you wrote 生。It has clear starts and ends to the lines. Some of the other characters seem a little too round for my liking but it is all personal taste. Another thing to take note of is that you don't need to write everything in one stroke just because you can. Sometimes it may be better to lift and start another stroke. Cheers :)